# Custom html/javascript in Sproutcore?

Tags: sproutcore

Is it possible to have custom html/javascript in Sproutcore?

I have to use some code from a cloud service provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is rather easy. In your view you can define a `render()` method:

```
App.myView = SC.View.extend({

  render: function(context, firstTime) {
    var someValue = `getValue`

    context.push(
      "<span class='mySpan'>", someValue, "</span>",
      "Any Other html/javascript that you want, can go here."
    );

  }

})
```

You can also use the `firstTime` property to know if you are rendering the first time (put out everything), or just updating the existing code.

You can find out more:

- http://guides.sproutcore.com/views.html#the-render-and-update-methods
- http://frozencanuck.wordpress.com/2009/08/14/creating-a-simple-custom-view-in-sproutcore-part1/